# Bind element inside If Block

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have this if block that checks if the user is logged with google or not

but this causes a problem where the google api takes a second to load, so the element is not on screen yet and I cant reference him even trough bind

How can I solve this issue?

```
let testBtn;

onMount(()=>{
    [...]

   console.log(testBtn)
})

[...]

{#if userLogged === false}
        <button class="text-lg text-black bg-white px-5 py-2 border-2 border-white rounded-2xl hover:bg-transparent hover:text-white transition-all duration-200" on:click={login}>Login with Google</button>
    {:else if userLogged === true}
    <div class="flex items-center">
        <h3 class="text-lg mr-5">Olá {username}</h3>
        <div class="relative group">
            [...]
                <button class="rounded-md p-2 bg-slate-100 hover:bg-slate-200 text-black my-2 btnAddCampaing" id="btnAddCampaing" bind:this={testBtn}>Criar uma campanha</button>
                <button class="rounded-md p-2 bg-slate-100 hover:bg-slate-200 text-black my-2" on:click={()=>signOut(auth).then(()=>{})}>Sair</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {/if}
```

Comment: Why do you need to bind to the button? Understanding your use case will help in offering alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's unclear when the button element will be created (maybe never if the user doesn't log in) using an action which will be called when an element is created could be an alternative. - [Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action) - [Tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/actions)

```
<script>
    function onCreation(node) {
        console.log(node) // button element
    }
</script>

{#if userLogged === false}
    ...
{:else if userLogged === true}
    ...
    <button id="btnAddCampaing" use:onCreation>
        Criar uma campanha
    </button>
    ... 
{/if}
```

Comment: I solved it this morning, but that anyway

The bind was working, its just that my brain is small, I was trying to console.log the object onMount, but as I tried $:{console.log(button)} I found out that was working.

I just began with svelte so I guess it was a begginers problem

Comment: small brain happens to the best of us. Sometimes the coffee just aint fresh.